# Connection betweem treewidth and feedback vertex set

Tags: graphs

I've learnt during graph algorithms studies that if a treewidth of a graph is greater than k+1 then there's no feedback vertex set of size k in this graph.
I would like to understand why...I mean, I understand that if it's enough to remove k vertices to make the grapy acyclic, so there must be a tree composition whose width is at most k,. but I cant fully understand the connection.
Can someone please elaborate it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the treewidth of an acyclic graph? How does the treewidth change when you delete (or add) a vertex from/to a graph?

Comment: Treewidth of an acyclic graph is either 1 if it's connected, too (since acyclic and connected graph is actually a tree...) And if it's a forest...hmm, what's the treewidth of a forest? And when you delete a vertex from the graph, the treewidth might improve up to 1 vertex, right? Makes sense?